# Can't login into sparkR docker container

Tags: docker, apache-spark

I downloaded thin sparkR and used the container before

https://hub.docker.com/r/jharner/rspark-rstudio

But now when I try to start the container again:

```
sudo docker run -e PASSWORD=pass -p 8787:8787 jharner/rspark-rstudio:0.9.7
```

I get the following error:

```
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8787: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

The address is indeed been used, but I'm unable to login:

[image]

I'm i do not have the corresponding container runnin either

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, the application is already running but not by docker - not too sure what has happened without more context.

Try finding out what process is using the port:

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:8787
```

If you're certain you can remove this, kill it with:

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

Then try starting the container you originally tried.

```
sudo docker run -e PASSWORD=pass -p 8787:8787 jharner/rspark-rstudio:0.9.7
```